# Visual Studio: Writing hints visible in other projects

Tags: c#, visual-studio, deployment, documentation, comments

Using Visual Studio 2013 and .NET I've created set of widgets which I want to use in external projects. Each class and method is well documented with the XML-style comments. For example:

```
///<summary>...</summary>
```

When I use already commented code within the same solution, the appearing prompt suggesting how to finish the line contains my remarks. Nevertheless, when I tried to generate a DLL file with the code and use it in the external project the comments were not available anymore. How can I document code to make these hints visible in other projects using the compiled DLL?

Comment: You have to generate XML documentation (see Project Properties) and to deploy them together with your DLL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use Code Documentation when referencing dll you have to generate XML documentation. XML documentation has to be in same folder that .dll is in.

[image]